Static declarations in enums, how do they work?
I have defined an enum, with a static property which loads a unit from user defaults. My question is how is this static property initialized? When a user changes defaults within my app, this property is not updated until restart.
enum Length: String, Some Protocols {
     //...some stuff
     static let preferredUnit: UnitLength = UserDefaults.standard.getUnit(forKey: .preferredUnitLength) 
} 

When I make this static constant a computed property, it's still not updated when a user changes their preferred unit despite updating defaults on unit change.
enum Length: String, Some Protocols {
     //...some stuff
     var preferredUnit: UnitLength { UserDefaults.standard.getUnit(forKey: .preferredUnitLength) }
} 

I leverage this static constant like so:
var someProperty: Measurement<UnitLength> {
     return value.converted(to: Length.preferredUnit)
}

The new unit is only loaded on app restart. I am okay with this, but would like to understand why.


When a user changes defaults within my app, this property is not updated until restart.
enum Length: String, Some Protocols {
    static let preferredUnit: UnitLength = UserDefaults.standard.getUnit(forKey: .preferredUnitLength) 
} 


How could it be "updated", under any circumstances? It is a let constant! That means that, once initialized, it is never changed.
As for your second formulation:

enum Length: String, Some Protocols {
    var preferredUnit: UnitLength { UserDefaults.standard.getUnit(forKey: .preferredUnitLength) }
} 


Now what you have is effectively a function; it runs every time any code says Length.preferredUnit. So in principle this does what you want (as I understand what you want); but I don't see any evidence that you ever say Length.preferredUnit, and you have not explained what getUnit is, so more can be said at this point.

getunit simply loads the value for the key from defaults. Apologies updated the code for consistency. I have a Length, Volume, etc preferredUnit.

Well there isn't enough info in your question to confirm / reproduce your claims. I assure you that if preferredUnit is a computed property and someProperty is a computed property, they are functions that run every time they are fetched. If not, something is going on that you have not told us (perhaps having to do with protocols?) and you would need to use the debugger to figure out what it is. Alternatively make a tiny test project that demonstrates your claims and I'll be glad to look at it.
